# Comment traduire « (legacy) » dans « Informations sur le document (legacy) » ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais, adjectifs

> Informations sur le document (legacy)

Le mot [*legacy*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legacy#dictionary-entry-2) qualifie tout ce qui le précède. Comment puis-je traduire « legacy » ici, est-ce avec un nom, un adjectif ou un adverbe, et si c'était avec un adjectif, y aura-t-il accord en genre et et nombre, et avec quoi ?

Comment: "**Historique**" could work although it's more likely to be associated with "history".

Comment: Informations complémentaires *ou* Informations contextuelles ?

Comment: en informatique: informations existantes ou héritées. p.ex. l'intégration avec des systèmes existants.

Comment: Encore une fois, un peu plus de contexte serait utile...

Comment: C'est littéralement dans les règles du site : "*if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.*" Sinon le risque est d'avoir une longue liste de réponses à la Prévert qui ne seront pas utiles pour les visiteurs futurs et le wiki, et une discussion qui s'étale dans le temps pour essayer de préciser le sujet, dégradant la qualité du signal avec des réponses éditées, commentaires qui deviennent obsolètes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Si ce sont les informations sur le document qui sont *legacy* :

> **Informations sur le document (non mises à jour)**

ou bien, mais peu courant sous cette forme :

> **Informations sur le document (caduques)**

Answer (score 3):

[L'office québécois de la langue française](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/8390449/systeme-herite) propose 3 traductions concernant les systèmes informatiques qui pourraient convenir ici :

> **document hérité**

Traduction littérale, on gagne une proximité avec l'anglais pour les initié.e.s

> **document patrimonial**

Comme hérité, mais me semble trop lié au jargon légal

> **document obsolète**

Le sens est beaucoup plus clair, mais semble indiquer que le document n'est plus du tout utilisable.

---

Entre ces trois termes, `hérité` a ma préférence.
Quand à la question d'accord en genre et en nombre, je pense que j'utiliserais le nom en description.

> **Informations sur le document (héritage)**

Sinon cela dépend si on parle des informations (`héritées`) ou du document (`hérité`)